# Rails 4 validations uses the message "too_long" instead of the "to_short"

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I use a range to define the length of the password, when user wants to change his password:

```
  validates :password, confirmation: true, length: {
      in: 6..20, 
      too_short: "to short message",
      too_long: "too long message"}
```

but if the input is too short, the error message is the to long, **why?**

[image]

[image]

I use for translations I18n via config/models/locales/en.yml, and there the error is the same, I use this example because es easier to explain

Comment: why won't you just go with single message inclusion: { in: 6..20, message: 'should be in range 6..20'}

Comment: Well.. in fact I don't use on-line messages, I use I18n in locale/en.yml files for translation

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I use **BCrypt**, and this stores a value bigger than  20 characters, encrypted value in password field

So that the solution is to move all validations to the password_confirmation field:

```
validates :password, confirmation: true
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, length: {in: 6..20}, if: "verify_password==0"
```

Now I get a correct error if I enter a value less than 6 characters size

[image]